# Necessary and sufficient condition for a field to be algebraic.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E \diagup  K$ be an extension. Prove that $E \diagup K$ is algebraic if and only if every subring $R$ of $E$ containing $K$ is a field.

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you at least explicate in which direction you get stuck with, and at which step you encounter difficulty. If $E/K$ is algebraic, you need to show that any nonzeros of a sub $K$-algebra of $E$ are invertible, and if $E/K$ is transcendental, you need to construct a non-field sub $K$-algebra.

Comment: @FrankScience I know how to prove that every subring $R$ is a field but I cannot prove the reverse. I mean, I got stuck in proving that if every subring $R$ of $E$ cintaining $K$ is a field then $E \diagup K$ id algebraic.

Comment: You'd better add what you did (or explaining what you can do) into your original post. For the later past, I have hinted above: you can try to prove its contraposition.

Comment: @FrankScience thank you so much

Comment: Hint: Show that if $z\in E\setminus K$ is transcendental over $K$, then the ring $K[z]$ is isomorphic to the ring of univariate polynomials $K[x]$.